# jQuery textbox focus() place cursor anywhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, cursor, focus

I have a javascript below:

```
function modify(value){
    $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
    $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
    $(value).addClass('ajax');
    $(value).html(
            '<input id="editbox"' + ' type="text" value="' + $(value).text() + '"/>');
    $('#editbox').focus();
}
```

Problem is that the cursor is placed at the beginning. Is there a solution I can place it wherever I want? F.e. if I click in the middle of the text I want the cursor to be there so I can edit the text from there on.

Thanks

EDIT:
I can only modify my value if I navigate with the left/right arrows to the position I want. If I click into the middle, the cursor disappers.

**Got It! Will paste code later**

Comment: What was your solution in the end? Can you paste your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position the cursor at the end of the text:

```
$(document).on('focus','#editbox',function(){        
     this.value = this.value;
});
```